# How do I access methods from a Class with an Object from another?

Tags: inheritance, polymorphism

I'm new to object orientation and I think this is me trying to use polymorphism and also doing it terribly but I need help. I have my DSAQueue class which is supposed to construct a Queue but is made from an array. However I have another class called ShufflingQueue which is in charge of shuffling all the elements of the array forward and backwards. How do I essentially make an object of the DSAQueue and construct a queue, and use a method from the ShufflingQueue class?

```
public class DSAQueue
{
    public static int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 100;

    //Classfields
    Object[] queue = null;
    int count;
  
    //default constructor 
    public DSAQueue()
    {
        queue = new Object[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

```
public class ShufflingQueue extends DSAQueue
{
    public void enqueue(int value)
    {
        queue[count] = value;
        count++;
    }
}
    

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    DSAQueue queue = new ShufflingQueue();

    //Declare DSAqueues 
    queue = new DSAQueue();

    //Fill the second queue up
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        queue.enqueue(2 * i + (i / 4));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please elaborate a bit on what you're trying to accomplish? If I understand correctly, you want to run the constructor of the DSAQueue class, then fill up the queue object with ShufflingQueue's enqueue method? If that's so, then you can just switch these two lines:

```
DSAQueue queue = new ShufflingQueue();
//Declare DSAqueues
queue = new DSAQueue();
```

With this one:

```
ShufflingQueue queue = new ShufflingQueue();
```

Because, if you don't have an argument inside the base class constructor, then it'll automatically run. If you'd have a constructor with an argument there, then you'd need to call the super() method from the derived class constructor and pass in the argument.